# Why need the variable currentScreen to be assigned two times in Android official compose sample project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the Android official compose sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab).

1: I don't understand why author need to assign the varaiable `currentScreen` for the two times in Code A, and it seems that both Code B and Code C can work well, could you tell me why?

2: In Code A `onScreenChange = { screen ->  currentScreen = RallyScreen.valueOf(screen) }`, where is the paramter `screen` (It's a sting) assigned?

3: Is Code A a good design? It's hard to understand. If Code C is correct, I  think the Code C is easy to see, how about my thinking?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RallyApp() {
    RallyTheme {
        val allScreens = RallyScreen.values().toList()
        var currentScreen by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(RallyScreen.Overview) }
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                RallyTabRow(
                    allScreens = allScreens,
                    onTabSelected = { screen -> currentScreen = screen },  //It's One time
                    currentScreen = currentScreen
                )
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Box(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                currentScreen.content(
                    onScreenChange = { screen ->
                        currentScreen = RallyScreen.valueOf(screen)      //It's Two time
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


enum class RallyScreen(
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val body: @Composable ((String) -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    Overview(
        icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
        body = { OverviewBody() }
    ),
    Accounts(
        icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
        body = { AccountsBody(UserData.accounts) }
    ),
    Bills(
        icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,
        body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) }
    );

    @Composable
    fun content(onScreenChange: (String) -> Unit) {
        body(onScreenChange)
    }
    
    ...  
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun RallyApp() {
    RallyTheme {
        ...
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Box(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                currentScreen.content(
                    onScreenChange = {null }   // I changed 
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

...//The same as Code A
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun RallyApp() {
    RallyTheme {
        ...
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Box(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                currentScreen.body()
            }
        }
    }
}


enum class RallyScreen(
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val body: @Composable () -> Unit  //I changed
) {
    Overview(
        icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
        body = { OverviewBody() }
    ),
    Accounts(
        icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
        body = { AccountsBody(UserData.accounts) }
    ),
    Bills(
        icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,
        body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) }
    );
   ...
}
```

**Added:**

For the question 2, `body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) }`  ignore the paramter `((String) -> Unit)` just like the following code.

```
Bills(
    icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,
    body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) } //It  ignore the paramter ((String) -> Unit)
);
```

So in Code A `onScreenChange = { screen ->  currentScreen = RallyScreen.valueOf(screen) },` is not used because the main branch of the project is not complete code, right?

Comment: I don't know anything about Compose, but for your first two questions, that's a lambda expression: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions It's a function that takes a single parameter (on the left side of the `->`) and does something with it. By default a single param is named `it`, but you can call it whatever makes it more readable, and whoever wrote that called it `screen` in both functions, probably because it represents one! They're internal to their functions, so there's no connection between them, except they're named the same for consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question 1, `currentScreen` is updated two time because there are two ways to change the current screen. User can either click on one of the TabRow icons or use the buttons in Overview Screen to navigate to a different screen. And the `onScreenChange` lambda in `RallyScreen.content()` function is to handle the second case (where current screen can be changed from inside of a screen)

Code B and C are working because the argument (`(String) -> Unit`) that `RallyScreen.body` takes is not used anywhere. That's why you are able to remove it in Code C. In Code B you are just ignoring that callback. `null` is not doing anything there.

Ideally this lambda argument should have been passed to the Overview screen. If you see the OverviewScreen composable, it accepts 3 parameters `onClickSeeAllAccounts`, `onClickSeeAllBills` and `onAccountClick`. That lambda should have been used to provide values to these arguments. But the author chose to ignore these and just use the default value `{}` for these params. That's why the "See All" buttons don't work in the starting point of codelab.

If you provide proper values to the three params, you will be able to navigate to Bills and Accounts screens from the Overview screen.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean the main branch of the project is not complete code? so it cause some  strange problem,  such as  in question 2, `onScreenChange = { screen ->  currentScreen = RallyScreen.valueOf(screen) }` is not be used in the main branch in the project, right?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Yes. The main branch does not have the complete code. As I mentioned in my answer, the buttons in Overview Screen don't work in the main branch code. And it seems that the author deliberately did that (can't say why).

Comment: @HelloCW Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank! It's great!